# Incorrect value date in debugger xcode?

Tags: xcode15

Why is it that when I select a date in DatePicker = 31/03/2024 in the debugger it shows as 30.03.2024?
How do I get the correct date value in the debugger?

```
    print(Date.now) - gives correct result

    print(dateX) - gives one day less
```